# Notification from Firebase cloud messaging are received but they are not shown in the cloud messaging reports

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notification to my android device. In my project console in the section "reports" I have 0 message received and 100 sended. The problem is that I actually received the notifications on my device but why do not they appear in the cloud messaging reports?

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I got the same problem. But I even have an analytics_label set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that statistic about message sended are updated in real-time, instead received, impression and message opened do not. I get these statistic the next day.

Please note that for "Data Message" you have to set in the message the field "analytics_label" in order to see statistics. For "Notification message" this should not be mandatory to see statistics.

Comment: In our firebase console, notification reports chart is showing no data. We are sending 1000's messages via API. Is there something missing, how to view these metrics in firebase console ?  We have not sent any messages via console.

Comment: @NavinGV which API are you using to send the messages ?
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid-abcd/messages:send

You have to use the second API to be able to track these labels.

Comment: @NishantChauhan Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Giorgos https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?authuser=0#adding-analytics-labels-to-messages

Comment: So, @NishantChauhan not only do you have to use HTTP v1 API but you also need to set the `fcmOptions.analyticsLabel` field in order to see statistics? Because this is not what the accepted answer says, at least for notifications.