# Firebase Cloud Messaging Reports wrong

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending cloud-messages to my app but Firebase-CF-Reports tells me that they would not be received:

But I know for sure that some devices do receive them. e.g. my own. So something is going wrong here in the reports.

I read about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707389/notification-from-firebase-cloud-messaging-are-received-but-they-are-not-shown-i) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049251/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-vs-received) but I already have an analytics-label that I send with my cloud-message.

This is how I sent my notifications with java-admin-sdk:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
                .setTopic(topic)
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
                        .build())
                .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                        .setAps(Aps.builder()
                                .setMutableContent(true)
                                .setContentAvailable(true)
                                .build())
                        .putHeader("apns-push-type", "background")
                        .putHeader("apns-priority", "5")
                        .putHeader("apns-topic", "my.bundle.id")
                        .build())
                .putData("\"content\"", contentString)
                .putData("\"actionButtons\"", actionButtonsString)
                .setFcmOptions(FcmOptions.withAnalyticsLabel("SendToAll"))
                .build();
```

[image]

Also interesting is, that If I am not filtering for `Platform/Channel` (altough still filter only for my android app with `Apps=`) I get this:

[image]

But these numbers still don't make any sense. I also opened some notifications on my own device. And I can't believe that only 18 were received.

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

I use this fcm-sdk in my flutter app:

```
firebase_messaging: ^9.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite I did not find this in the official documentation, I found information in this discussion in the comments to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055267/2813152). Turns out that subscribing to a topic in FCM is not necessarily permanent. So don't subscribe users to a topic once. Instead do it on every app start, although it is

> "not technically necessary. It may depend on your use case. For
> example, if you want a global topic where all users are a member of,
> you'd have to make sure that they are subscribed to it. Putting the
> subscribe method when the app starts guarantees this."

- -@AL.

Since I changed that, the Notifications are received by a lot more people than before. Only the open-count is still not working for me. It is always on zero.